# Add common Startup Folder to VS2008 Setup Solution

Tags: c#, setup-project

When you right click the File System on Target Machine tree and select Add Special Folder inside a setup application you get a list of options.  One is User's Startup Folder....however there is no option for Common/All Startup Folder.  Is there a way to specify the common/all startup folder as a custom folder and still have it work properly in XP, Vista, and Win7?

Comment: Doesn't that depend on whether you're installing for "all users" or just the "current user"? If you want to force it to always install for all users, I think there's a flag for that...

Comment: No, regardless of the picked setting, the shortcut always gets placed in the user startup folder and I'm trying to get it in All Users.  You can manually set a flag in the solution to force it to always install for all users and not give that option, but again that does not alter where the shortcut appears.

Answer (score 0):

Select the `Deployment Project Properties` and set the `InstallAllUsers` option to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little microsoft walk-through:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/716bxh4e(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa372057%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You will also need to set the **InstallAllUsers** to **TRUE** and replace the '**[TempFolder]**' from the example with '**[StartupFolder]**'